# Use Nginx to run PHP and React side by side

Tags: php, reactjs, nginx

I'm relatively new to Docker, Nginx, etc. and have been searching for days for solutions but haven't found one. I'm transitioning from one stack to another so I need to keep existing functionality while refactoring. I'm trying to use Nginx to run PHP and React side by side where routes containing /php/ will display PHP and everything else will run React:

```
server {
    server_name _;
    listen 80;
    root /var/www;
    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;

    location /php/ {
        #try_files $uri =404;
        alias /var/www;
        index index.php index.html;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?q=$uri&$args;
        fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        include fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
    }

    location / {
        root /react-app;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        default_type "text/html";

        #proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
        #proxy_http_version 1.1;
        #proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        #proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        #proxy_set_header Host $host;
        #proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

I get forbidden errors and internal server errors constantly. Any ideas how to accomplish this?

Note: I run all of these containers locally without Nginx without a problem but because of how we have our servers set up (each container gets its own subdomain), when I put them on Portainer I need to configure Nginx.

[Console error output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhPCO.png)

Comment: `I get forbidden errors and internal server errors`, include those in your question.

Comment: Like the console output?